# Как получить данные из 3-х связанных таблиц? Со вложенностью

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many, one-to-many

Как получить данные из 3-х связанных таблиц в одном запросе?
База данный MySQL

```
Products(product_id, title, price) 
Order(order_id, user_id, order_date, status)
Order_products(order_id, product_id, amount)
```

Хочу получить данные в виде:

```
order_id, product_title, product_price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT op.order_id,p.product_title, p.product_price FROM Order_products op LEFT JOIN Products p ON (op.product_id=p.product_id) ORDER BY op.order_id

таблица order для получения order_id, product_title, product_price не нужна